# PolymerJs table change color of cell based on data (JSON)

Tags: javascript, arrays, polymer, polymer-1.0

requirement : [Table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bgdjC.png)

How can i achieve this using polymerJS,

click on the image to know more.

i need to change color(s) of the cells based on different data values from JSON.

Comment: it would be great to add some code. like what is the structure of JSON...... what have you already tried. Just write some more info. What you asked is really general and we need details

Answer (score 0):

Do something like  ,

and then return class name that controls the color in that function.